# retrieving data from a numpy array and storing in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I currently have a .npy file and I would like to store the data it contains in a variable in order to convert it to a dataframe.

I tried using the following:

```
data_array=np.load('Jason1Data_Full_East_West.npy')
df = pd.DataFrame(data_array)
```

However my dataframe came out as a single column. How do I save the data in a format where the columns are clearly separated with now square brackets around the rows?

Below is the result I am currently getting.
[image]

Comment: You must provide a [mcve] for us to diagnose the problem.

Comment: It looks like your data was never structured properly in the first place.

Comment: It was sent to me. Is there a way to get it in the format I want?

Answer (score 1):

Even your question is not clear. You can try the following:

```
path = .../Jason1Data_Full_East_West.npy
data = np.load(path)
```

And then you need to convert it to dataframe as the following:

```
pd.DataFrame({'Data':data.tolist()})
```

Comment: Jason != JSON. Jason is also a common male name.

Comment: Sorry Arya, I didn't fully understand the question.  Now I corrected the answer. please comment :)

Comment: Don't forget quotes for the path. Is `tolist` necessary? What about `pd.DataFrame(data)`?

Comment: I have edited the question a bit because I have encountered this situation again. Could you guys provide me with some assistance please?